# Linking Entries from Two Columns

Tags: vba, excel

[image]I have IDs in two columns, let's say column A and column B. In these columns are ids and they will appear in either a or b multiple times. What I'd like to do is provide a batch number like the example below, where any related ID is put under one batch.

Are there any good ideas of how to do this in excel/vba? I have 15000 rows. So far I have tried looping through each row and trying to tag 1 with 2, then 2 to 4 etc but the for loops suddenly become almost unlimited. I don't care about providing code, it's more the logic side!

Comment: What do you mean by a "related" ID? Do you mean the same or a partial match. How is a Batch Number derived from the ID?

Comment: Hi John. Related ID is the linked relationship. So in my screenshot above, a1 links to b1 and b1 links to c1 so they are all batches or maybe an easier term dependencies. The batch number would be a unique identifier for all related dependencies for one batch.

Comment: Can a later entry link to an earlier one? e.g. could row 5 be X1 > A1

Comment: Yep - they link both ways as well.. So it could be A1 > X1 and they should be linked.

Comment: Hmm. so half-way down the list you might think you have two separate groups then suddenly an entry in one group links to an entry in the other and hey presto you realise they are all members of the same group?

Comment: Correct! Absolute nightmare.. I can't even get a proper do while loop working because it seems to go down into multiple loops.. It's a one time thing so if there's a manual codey way to do it I'm all ears.

Comment: Could you perhaps cut down the size of the current screenshot and add another one which illustrates your desired results?

Comment: Declare them as recordsets and use SQL to join them?

Comment: Will the data always be two columns?

Comment: Yes data will always be in two columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a modification on 19Oct of the code that I posted on 18Oct which had a serious bug and some other failings. Hopefully this version is more effective. I have put a note about the bug at the end of this post.

This solution utilises a class, cGroup which represents the identifier for a group, where a group is defined as all the strings in col A and col B that appear on the same rows. So membership of a group means that somewhere in the worksheet there is a row on which there are two members of the same group, and at least one of those members also appears on another row in the list (unless both values appear only once, on the same row, and they have a group of their very own). Each group has an original class ID which it is assigned when it is created, but it might be linked later to another, parent, group (see below), in which case it adopts the class id of its parent group.

The code runs down the list, and assigns the key values in col A and col B to a pre-existing group if either key has previously appeared in the list. If neither has previously appeared, then a new group with a new class ID is created for them. If they have both previously appeared on different rows and been assigned to different groups, then the groups must be linked. This is by choosing one group to be the parent of the other, which can then form a hierarchy of child>parent relationships. The child group adopts the classID of its parent - the ClassID property contains the logic for this. The big advantage of this approach is that it avoids large-scale iteration, although there is still iteration up the child>Parent ClassID hierarchy to discover the ClassID of a child lower in the hiearchy.

I use Scripting.Dictionary to provide a lookup from a key to its class. To use this in your code set up a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime library in Tools > References.

I have implemented the code that processes the key data as a separate class cGrouper with a single method, AllocateClassIDs, which is given a 3-column area of a worksheet to process - the three columns being the KeyA, KeyB inputs on each row of the first two columns and the corresponding output class number in the third column. To use this class the code will be something like:

```
Public Sub run()

    Dim oGrouper As New cGrouper

    '// rTestData1 is a named range in the a worksheet that is 3 columns x n rows, containing n pairs of keys
    '// in col1 and col2. the allocated class number is written into column 3 of the range
    oGrouper.AllocateClassIDs [rTestData1]

End Sub
```

Here is the code for the cGrouper class:

```
Option Explicit
'// This class will identify groups of related key values in two Key columns of a worksheet and then assign group numbers.
'// A group is defined as the set of Keys that appear on the same rows in the two key columns. So if A and B are on
'// row 3 and B and C on row 4, then A, B and C are in the same group, along with any other key values that share
'// the same relationship with each other.

'// Corollary: Keys are in different goups only if each key in the group never appears on the same row as any of the keys in any other group



'// Dictionaries
'// Lookup from a key value to the related class. Key value is a string that appears in colA or colB
Dim GroupMembers As New Scripting.Dictionary

'// Lookup to the groups that have already been created. The key is the GroupGroupID (integer assigned on creation)
Dim Groups As New Scripting.Dictionary


'// This subroutine does all the work
    Public Sub AllocateClassIDs(Keys As Range)

        '// First clear out the dictionaries
        GroupMembers.RemoveAll
        Groups.RemoveAll

        g.Reset

        '// Check the given ranges
        If Keys.Columns.Count <> 3 Then
            MsgBox "Range must have three columns - cannot process"
            Exit Sub
        End If

        '// Set up references to the sub-ranges within the sheet
        Dim KeysA As Range, KeysB As Range, ClassIDs As Range

        Set KeysA = Keys.Columns(1)
        Set KeysB = Keys.Columns(2)
        Set ClassIDs = Keys.Columns(3)



        Dim iRow As Integer, sAKey As String, sBKey As String
        Dim iAGroup As cGroup, iBGroup As cGroup

        '// Run down every row of the given range
        For iRow = 1 To KeysA.Rows.Count

            '// Get the key values from Col A and Col B
            sAKey = KeysA.Cells(iRow)
            sBKey = KeysB.Cells(iRow)

            '// Check if these keys have already been found earlier
            If GroupMembers.Exists(sAKey) Then Set iAGroup = GroupMembers.Item(sAKey) Else Set iAGroup = Nothing
            If GroupMembers.Exists(sBKey) Then Set iBGroup = GroupMembers.Item(sBKey) Else Set iBGroup = Nothing


            '// Now check the combination of possibilities:
            Select Case True
                Case iAGroup Is Nothing And iBGroup Is Nothing

                    '// Neither key was found so we need to create a new group to hold the class number
                    If Len(sAKey) > 0 Or Len(sBKey) > 0 Then
                        With New cGroup
                            '// Add the group to the dictionary of groups
                             Groups.Add .GroupID, .Self

                            '// Add the keys to the dictionary of group members. This links the key to the group
                            If Len(sAKey) > 0 Then GroupMembers.Add sAKey, .Self
                            If sAKey <> sBKey And Len(sBKey) > 0 Then GroupMembers.Add sBKey, .Self
                        End With
                    End If
                Case iBGroup Is Nothing
                    '// Key in col A is already in a group from an earlier line, but key in Col B is not
                    '// we just add ColB key to the same group as the col A key
                    If Len(sBkey)>0 Then
                        Set iAGroup = GroupMembers.Item(sAKey)
                        GroupMembers.Add sBKey, iAGroup
                    End If

                Case iAGroup Is Nothing
                    '// Key in Col B is already in a group, but Key in col A is not
                    '// We just add ColA key to the same group as the col B key
                    IF Len(sAkey)>0 Then
                        Set iBGroup = GroupMembers.Item(sBKey)
                        GroupMembers.Add sAKey, iBGroup
                    End IF


                Case Else
                    '// They are both already in a group. That's fine if they are members of the same class but...
                    If iAGroup.ClassID <> iBGroup.ClassID Then

                        '// They are in DIFFERENT Classes so we must merge them together by settung
                        '// the class ID of one group to be the same as the other

                            '// Always use the lower-numbered class ID
                            If iAGroup.ClassID < iBGroup.ClassID Then
                                iBGroup.JoinGroupMembership iAGroup
                            Else
                                iAGroup.JoinGroupMembership iBGroup
                            End If


                    End If
                End Select

        Next iRow


        '// Remember the last row
        Dim iLastRow As Integer: iLastRow = iRow - 1

        '// Assign the class numbers. This just makes sure each unique class has a number, starting at 1.
        Dim ClassNumbers As New Scripting.Dictionary
        Dim ix As Integer

        Dim iGroup As cGroup
        Dim iClassNumber As Integer

        For ix = 0 To Groups.Count - 1
            '// Get the next group object
            Set iGroup = Groups.Item(Groups.Keys(ix))

            '// Check if this is a "ROOT" group, i.e. the group ID is the same as the class ID
            If iGroup.bIsRootGroup Then
                iClassNumber = iClassNumber + 1
                'If iClassNumber = 30 Then MsgBox "Classnumber 30"

                '// Add it to the dictionary of class numbers
                ClassNumbers.Add iGroup.ClassID, iClassNumber
            End If

        Next ix

        '// Finally, we can assign the class numbers to the rows in the spreadsheet
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

        For ix = 1 To iLastRow

            '// Put the relevant class number into column 3
            ClassIDs.Cells(ix) = ClassNumbers.Item(GroupMembers.Item(KeysA.Cells(ix).Value).ClassID)

        Next ix
         Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

        MsgBox "done"

    End Sub
```

Here is the code of the cGroup Class

```
    Option Explicit

    '// Properties of the class
    Public GroupID As Integer

    '// The group master of this class (i.e. another group to which it has been joined)
    '// Can be Nothing if not joined to any other group or if this is the master group 
    '// of a set of joined groups
    Private memberOfGroup As cGroup


    Private Sub class_initialize()
        '// Assign an ID to myself
        GroupID = g.NextGroupID

        '// I am not a member of any other group
        Set memberOfGroup = Nothing

    End Sub

    Public Sub JoinGroupMembership(NewLinkedGroup As cGroup)
        '// Links this group to membership of another group.
        '// Note that this group may already be a member of another group, in which case
        '// group membership is changed on the parent group as well as this group

        '// To avoid circular references, the group with the lower classid is always chosen to be the parent

        If NewLinkedGroup.ClassID > Me.ClassID Then
            NewLinkedGroup.JoinGroupMembership Me
            Exit Sub
        End If

        '// If I am already member of a group, make sure my parent group
        '// joins the new group
        If Not memberOfGroup Is Nothing Then
            memberOfGroup.JoinGroupMembership NewLinkedGroup
        End If

        '// Now set the new linked group to be my parent
        Set memberOfGroup = NewLinkedGroup


    End Sub


    Public Function ClassID() As Integer
    '// Returns the classID of this group's master group
    '// Note that this is recursive, it will work up through the hierarchy of
    '// parent groups until it hits the group with no parent.


        '// Check if I am the master group
        If memberOfGroup Is Nothing Then
            '// Return my GroupID as the classID
            ClassID = GroupID
        Else
            '// Return the classID of my parent
            ClassID = memberOfGroup.ClassID
        End If

    End Function

    Public Function bIsRootGroup() As Boolean
    '// Returns true if this group is not a member of another group
        bIsRootGroup = memberOfGroup Is Nothing
    End Function

    Public Function Self() As cGroup
        Set Self = Me

    End Function
```

Here is the code of a Module which I have named g

```
    Option Explicit

    '// Global register of Group ID
    Private gMaxGroupNumber As Integer

    '// Method to get the next available GroupID
    Public Function NextGroupID() As Integer
        gMaxGroupNumber = gMaxGroupNumber + 1
        NextGroupID = gMaxGroupNumber

    End Function

    '// Method to reset the groupID
    Public Sub Reset()
        gMaxGroupNumber = 0

    End Sub
```

---

About the bug: In my earlier version of the code the group hierarchy did not work because it was a simple allocation of a parent classID to a group. This is fine as long as the groups were joined in a controlled sequence, but if two separate groups had already formed, then a later sequence of merging of two groups could isolate previously-linked members - their classIDs did not get updated with the new parent class so they were effectively orphaned.

Comment: interesting approach, but suggest to use fully qualified range reference and to change the identification  `Me.` within your worksheet code to avoid error messages.

Comment: Hi John! Thanks this is really elegant. It's blank for about 20 values even though there's a valid link. What are the parameters where it won't fill in a number?

Comment: @Wickey312 Yes I have found the same problem when I increased my sample size to large number of entries. I have found the problem and working on the solution.

Comment: @T.M. Good points - the coding was rushed I will fix in revised version.

Comment: @johnrc I appreciate it! Also would be interested to know what the issue is when you've worked out the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions:

- First column always contains start link
- Second column always contains chain link
- To continue the link chain, what is listed in second column must later be found in first column to continue the chain (as shown in your example).  This prevents "link splitting" where a link can split into different chains.

If these assumptions are true, then this code will work for you:

```
Sub tgr()

    Const Link1Col As String = "A"
    Const Link2Col As String = "B"
    Const LinkIDCol As String = "C"

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim linkColumns(1 To 2) As Range
    Dim FoundLink As Range
    Dim LinkID As Long
    Dim i As Long

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    Set linkColumns(1) = ws.Range(Link1Col & "1", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, Link1Col).End(xlUp))
    Set linkColumns(2) = Intersect(linkColumns(1).EntireRow, ws.Columns(Link2Col))

    Intersect(linkColumns(1).EntireRow, ws.Columns(LinkIDCol)).ClearContents
    LinkID = 0

    For i = linkColumns(1).Row To linkColumns(1).Row + linkColumns(1).Rows.Count - 1
        If Len(ws.Cells(i, LinkIDCol).Value) = 0 Then
            LinkID = LinkID + 1
            ws.Cells(i, LinkIDCol).Value = LinkID
            Set FoundLink = linkColumns(1).Find(ws.Cells(i, Link2Col).Value, , xlValues, xlWhole)
            If Not FoundLink Is Nothing Then
                Do
                    ws.Cells(FoundLink.Row, LinkIDCol).Value = LinkID
                    Set FoundLink = linkColumns(1).Find(ws.Cells(FoundLink.Row, Link2Col).Value, , xlValues, xlWhole)
                Loop While Not FoundLink Is Nothing
            End If
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Tiger. Appreciate the attempt on this. First column doesn't always contain first link.. Could be other way round.